# View bounds dont update after changing orientation IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I have an issue with my app when I change orientation into a viewController. If I get into this view controller in portrait mode (320 width) and change to landscape then it seems that only 320 width of landscape mode is active and the rest screen seems to be dead. I tried to update view.Frame when the orientation changes but it didn't work. Can anyone help me with this?

```
- (void)updateLayoutForNewOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{
      if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
      {
    // Portrait

        self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,500);
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smallerView2.png"]];

        self.thumbScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(20,100, 280, 72);

        self.rightThumbArrow.frame=CGRectMake(1,107, self.rightThumbArrow.bounds.size.width, self.rightThumbArrow.bounds.size.height);

        self.leftThumbArrow.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width-30,107, self.leftThumbArrow.bounds.size.width, self.leftThumbArrow.bounds.size.height);

        self.bigImageView.frame=CGRectMake(20,200, 280, 200);

        self.previousPicBar.frame=CGRectMake(19,200, 10, 198);

        self.nextPicBar.frame=CGRectMake(291,200, 10, 198);

        self.leftArrowBtn.frame=CGRectMake(20,294, 8, 10);

        self.rightArrowBtn.frame=CGRectMake(292,294, 8, 10);



}

else
{
    // Landscape



        self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 320);

        NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f",self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smallerView2Landscape.png"]];

        self.thumbScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(30,60, 520, 60);

        self.rightThumbArrow.frame=CGRectMake(10,65, self.rightThumbArrow.bounds.size.width, self.rightThumbArrow.bounds.size.height);

        self.leftThumbArrow.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width-45,65, self.leftThumbArrow.bounds.size.width, self.leftThumbArrow.bounds.size.height);

        self.bigImageView.frame=CGRectMake(120,120, 350, 140);

        self.previousPicBar.frame=CGRectMake(119,122, 10, 136);

        self.nextPicBar.frame=CGRectMake(461,122, 10, 136);

        self.leftArrowBtn.frame=CGRectMake(120,180, 8, 10);

        self.rightArrowBtn.frame=CGRectMake(462,180, 8, 10);


}
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];

      [self updateLayoutForNewOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
 }

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
      [self updateLayoutForNewOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
}
```

Comment: How did you change the view.frame ? Can you post some code? In what method did you do that?

Comment: i edited my question with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mismatch in setting and getting view coordinate. you are setting frame in `- (void)updateLayoutForNewOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation` and in NSLog you are printing using bound.

Correct way to get width is following

```
NSLog(@"x= %f y= %f w= %f h=%f",self.view.frame.origin.x,
self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width,
self.view.frame.size.height);
```

your code

```
NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f",self.view.bounds.origin.x,
self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width,
self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

Change bound with frame or viceversa.

Comment: I posted the whole code which handle orientation. There are not other details. It is strange that when i print the width of self.view it gives me the right width. Although, when i print the coordinates of touch event it reaches only until 320 width and then nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0):

User that answered me had right.I had to change the way that i set the x,y,width,height.

**Changing**

```
self.view.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds
                                   .size.height);
```

**With**

```
self.view.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame
                                   .size.height);
```

and adding

```
[self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

in viewDidLoad method made the difference.